# Spring-boot: Accept any certificate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, nginx-config

I have developed an application based on micro-services. I have some troubles integrating 3 of them. The first service is a Spring-boot application which is connected to the second service, in charge of managing user's authentication, which is Keycloak. Finally, the access to those services is managed by a reverse-proxy service, here Nginx, in charge of securing communications with clients as illustrated here:
[image: micro-services architecture]

First of all, the client gets a token from keycloak, which works fine. Then, the client uses this token to access services from spring, which fails. The spring application is configured like this:

```
keycloak.realm=my-realm
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://172.17.0.1/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.resource=my-resource
keycloak.credentials.secret=my-secret
```

The auth-server IP is the IP of Docker. When I try to access the rest service, I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have tried to deactivate verification of certification with this code (kotlin) within my Spring application:

```
val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
sslContext.init(null, arrayOf<TrustManager>(ECollabTrustManager()), SecureRandom())
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory)
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier())
```

And here is the code of the TrustManager:

```
class ECollabTrustManager : X509TrustManager {
    override fun checkClientTrusted(certs: Array<out X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {
    }

    override fun checkServerTrusted(certs: Array<out X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {
    }

    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? {
        return null
    }

}
```

But it doesn't solve the error. Any idea ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you have to configure your Nginx server with SSL certificates?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually this configuration works locally (without nginx). The difference here is that the spring service is not directly connected to the keycloak service.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are already using `HostnameVerifier` that accepts all hosts as being valid (that `NoopHostnameVerifier`) so the ony piece left is to create and use a `TrustManager` that trusts all certs (plain Java follows):

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
{
   @Override
   public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
   {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException
   {
   }

   @Override
   public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException
   {

   }
} };

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: It is actually what I am doing (2nd line of the excerpt shown above). It doesn't change anything !

Comment: Is that the `ECollabTrustManager`? It would help if you can post its code. I'd suggest trying with the TrustManager in my answer - if it works then the problem probably has something to do with the `ECollabTrustManager`. For example, it may require a CA cert that isn't provided and/or it doesn't trust the cert presented by Nginx (assuming there's one). Yes, using a TrustManager that blindly trusts all certs isn't recommended for a Production environment - the idea here is to use such TrustManager to troubleshoot the issue. HTH

Comment: I have added the code of ECollabManager. For sure, I won't use it in production. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see that `ECollabManager` trusts all certs... After re-reading the question few things come to my mind: Is the communication from the React client to the Spring app/service intended to be end-to-end TLS/SSL? Is Nginx a passthrough for TLS traffic or does it offload it and then re-encrypts it after establishing new TLS connection with the Spring app? (perhaps the most important question) Does the Spring app/service have a cert and its private key configured?

Comment: Spring is not configured with ssl activated. The frontend talks only with the gateway. Certificates are then configured only for nginx.

Comment: Is the exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path...` in the Spring-based rest service? If that's the case and the Spring service isn't configured with cert and private key (or a keystore with them), I'd suggest to check in Nginx and make sure it is connecting to the Spring service using HTTP, not HTTPS.